# error: ‘root’ does not name a type

Tags: c++, struct, types, g++, incomplete-type

I get the following error for all attributes of a node, and for all nodes.

```
n-tree.h:35:2: error: ‘root’ does not name a type
  root->parent = NULL;
  ^
```

I want to create a tree with arbitrary number of child nodes. I created a header file for the tree definition.

I first defined a node as a struct.
Then using the definition of the Node, I created a Tree.

I tried many ways to resolve the error, example, by defining the Node struct inside the nTree struct, defining the nodes in other common implementations.

Here is n-tree.h

```
#ifndef N_TREE
#define N_TREE
#include <cstdio>

struct Node
{
    Node* parent;
    Node* left_child;
    Node* right_sibling;
    double key;
};

struct nTree
{

// Nodes - attributes of the tree
Node* root;
Node* node1_1;
    Node* node1_1_1;
    Node* node1_1_2;

Node* node1_2;
    Node* node1_2_1;
    Node* node1_2_2;
    Node* node1_2_3;

Node* node1_3;
    Node* node1_3_1;



// Root level
root->parent = NULL;
root->left_child = node1_1;
root->right_sibling = NULL;
root->key = 1;

// Level 1_1
node1_1->parent = root;
node1_1->left_child = node1_1_1;
node1_1->right_sibling = node1_2;
node1_1->key = 2;

// Level 1_2
node1_2->parent = root;
node1_2->left_child = node1_2_1;
node1_2->right_sibling = node1_3;
node1_2->key = 3;

// Level 1_3
node1_3->parent = root;
node1_3->left_child = node1_3_1;
node1_3->right_sibling = NULL;
node1_3->key = 4;


// Level 1_1_1
node1_1_1->parent = node1_1;
node1_1_1->left_child = NULL;
node1_1_1->right_sibling = node1_1_2;
node1_1_1->key = 5;

 // Level 1_1_2
node1_1_2->parent = node1_1;
node1_1_2->left_child = NULL;
node1_1_2->right_sibling = NULL;
node1_1_2->key = 6;

// Level 1_2_1
node1_2_1->parent = node1_2;
node1_2_1->left_child = NULL;
node1_2_1->right_sibling = node1_2_2;
node1_2_1->key = 7;

// Level 1_2_2
node1_2_2->parent = node1_2;
node1_2_2->left_child = NULL;
node1_2_2->right_sibling = node1_2_3;
node1_2_2->key = 8;

// Level 1_2_3
node1_2_3->parent = node1_2;
node1_2_3->left_child = NULL;
node1_2_3->right_sibling = NULL;
node1_2_3->key = 9;

// Level 1_3_1
node1_3_1->parent = node1_3;
node1_3_1->left_child = NULL;
node1_3_1->right_sibling = NULL;
node1_3_1->key = 10;

};
#endif
```

---

Here is n-tree_implement.cpp

```
#include <cstdio>
#include "n-tree.h"

int main()
{
    nTree* tree = new nTree;
    printf("%d\n", tree->root->key);
    delete tree;
}
```

The above header file when included gives the following error for all nodes within the nTree.

Comment: In C++, you don't need `struct` when declaring variables.  For example, `Node * root;` will work fine.

Comment: Please add the *exact error message, verbatim*, to your question.

Comment: I will edit the question. I have commented the Node * root definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lines:

```
root->parent = NULL;
root->left_child = node1_1;
root->right_sibling = NULL;
root->key = 1;
```

are not legal.

I am hesitant to suggest a solution because it's not clear from your code how you are intending to use `nTree`.

Comment: In other words, the lines should be in a method.

Comment: I want to define the structure of the tree and not create it dynamically using methods. eg. nTree *tree = new nTree; should create the Tree and printf("%d", tree->root->key); should print "1"

Comment: @arttp2, that is vague. you need more precise information. how may nodes do you want to create? what's the structure of the nodes? how deep do you want the tree to be? Once you have those answers, create a non-member function to create such a tree and fill up the tree as you see fit in that function.

Comment: I am replacing the code snippet with the intended tree structure.

Comment: @arttp2 first of all it is not clear how existence of class/struct methods related to dynamical creation of tree instances. Second, code in c++ must be in a function (except data declaration/definition), either standalone or that belong to classes (aka methods)

Comment: @arttp2, create a non-member function. Let's call it `construct_tree`. In the function, create a tree with just one node, the root node. Make sure it works. Then update the function to add another layer of nodes. Make sure it works. Keep updating the function until you have the desired structure.

Comment: @R Sahu, please check if the cpp should work that i have added to the original question. Also I created this "rigid" tree as opposed to a dynamically growing tree because I am focused on traversing rather than creating a tree, hence to avoid creating a tree repeatedly, I wrote the above header file.

Comment: @arttp2, no it won't work even if you move all of that code to a function. You are not allocating memory for any of the nodes.

Comment: @RSahu, the compiler should know the size of each node, hence allocate memory for the tree (hence all nodes)

Comment: @arttp2, `root` is a pointer to a node. You can use `root = new Node[10];` to allocate memory for ten root nodes, or you can use `root = new Node;` to allocate memory for one root node. How is the compiler supposed to know how you wish to allocate memory for that node?